# Running two dask-ml imputers simultaneously instead of sequentially

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-ml

I can impute the mean and most frequent value using dask-ml like so, this works fine:

```
mean_imputer = impute.SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
most_frequent_imputer = impute.SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
data = [[100, 2, 5], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [70, 7, 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Weight', 'Age', 'Height']) 
df.iloc[:, [0,1]] = mean_imputer.fit_transform(df.iloc[:,[0,1]])
df.iloc[:, [2]] = most_frequent_imputer.fit_transform(df.iloc[:,[2]])
print(df)


    Weight  Age   Height
0   100.0   2.0   5.0
1   85.0    4.5   5.0
2   70.0    7.0   5.0
```

But what if I have 100 million rows of data it seems that dask would do two loops when it could have done only one, is it possible to run both imputers simultaneously and/or in parallel instead of sequentially? What would be a sample code to achieve that?

Comment: I always though it already runs functions in parallel - and you don't have to do it manually. You would have somehow test time used by functions. Maybe it already run first `SimpleImputer` in parrallel processes - it split data to smaller parts and run then in separated processes (and it can use all CPU power) - and adding second `SimpleImputer` may not work faster.

Comment: In my example, `most_frequent_imputer.fit_transform` runs after `mean_imputer.fit_transform`, I need these to run in parallel

Comment: as I said: first you should check if `most_frequent_imputer` doesn't use already parallel automatically  and running another  `mean_imputer` at the same time may not help.

Comment: BTW: found with Google: [Dask: Parallelize code with dask.delayed](https://tutorial.dask.org/01_dask.delayed.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used [dask.delayed](https://tutorial.dask.org/01_dask.delayed.html#Parallelize-with-the-dask.delayed-decorator) as suggested in docs and [Dask Toutorial](https://tutorial.dask.org/01_dask.delayed.html) to parallelise the computation if entities are independent of one another.

Your code would look like:

```
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client(n_workers=4)

from dask import delayed
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dask_ml import impute

mean_imputer = impute.SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
most_frequent_imputer = impute.SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')

def fit_transform_mi(d):
    return mean_imputer.fit_transform(d)
def fit_transform_mfi(d):
    return most_frequent_imputer.fit_transform(d)
def setdf(a,b,df):
    df.iloc[:, [0,1]]=a
    df.iloc[:, [2]]=b
    return df

data = [[100, 2, 5], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [70, 7, 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Weight', 'Age', 'Height']) 
a = delayed(fit_transform_mi)(df.iloc[:,[0,1]])
b = delayed(fit_transform_mfi)(df.iloc[:,[2]])
c = delayed(setdf)(a,b,df)
df= c.compute()
print(df)
client.close()
```

The c object is a lazy Delayed object. This object holds everything we need to compute the final result, including references to all of the functions that are required and their inputs and relationship to one-another.

Answer (score 2):

Dask is useful for speeding computation by parallel processing and when the data does not fit in memory. In the example below, 300M rows of data contained in ten files are imputed using Dask. The graph of the process shows that: 1. The mean and most frequent imputers are run in parallel; 2. All ten files are processed in parallel as well.

#### Set-up

To prepare a large amount of data, the three rows of data in your question are replicated, to form a data frame with 30M rows. The data frame is saved in ten different files to yield a total of 300M rows with the same stats as in your question.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 10000000
weight = np.array([100, np.nan, 70]*N)
age = np.array([2, np.nan, 7]*N)
height = np.array([5, np.nan, 5]*N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weight': weight, 'Age': age, 'Height': height})

# Save ten large data frames to disk
for i in range(10):
    df.to_parquet(f'./df_to_impute_{i}.parquet', compression='gzip',
                  index=False)
```

#### Dask Imputation

```
import graphviz
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask_ml.impute import SimpleImputer

# Read all files for imputation in a dask data frame from a specific directory
df = dd.read_parquet('./df_to_impute_*.parquet')

# Set up the imputers and columns
mean_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
mostfreq_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
imputers = [mean_imputer, mostfreq_imputer]

mean_cols = ['Weight', 'Age']
freq_cols = ['Height']
columns = [mean_cols, freq_cols]

# Create a new data frame with imputed values, then visualize the computation.
df_list = []
for imputer, col in zip(imputers, columns):
    df_list.append(imputer.fit_transform(df.loc[:, col]))
imputed_df = dd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
imputed_df.visualize(filename='imputed.svg', rankdir='LR')

# Save the new data frame to disk
imputed_df.to_parquet('imputed_df.parquet', compression='gzip')
```

#### Output

[image]

```
imputed_df.head()

    Weight  Age     Height
0   100.0   2.0     5.0
1   85.0    4.5     5.0
2   70.0    7.0     5.0
3   100.0   2.0     5.0
4   85.0    4.5     5.0


# Check the summary statistics make sense - 300M rows and stats as expected
imputed_df.describe().compute()

    Weight  Age     Height
count   3.000000e+08    3.000000e+08    300000000.0
mean    8.500000e+01    4.500000e+00    5.0
std     1.224745e+01    2.041241e+00    0.0
min     7.000000e+01    2.000000e+00    5.0
25%     7.000000e+01    2.000000e+00    5.0
50%     8.500000e+01    4.500000e+00    5.0
75%     1.000000e+02    7.000000e+00    5.0
max     1.000000e+02    7.000000e+00    5.0
```

Comment: Great explanation, but I can only choose one answer

Comment: Does it scale to 100M rows?

Comment: Shouldn't dask make this transparent?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Delayed ensures the parallel computation. However, any Dask code can block your memory when the .compute() method is invoked. What works on a tiny data frame may not work on 300M rows. Therefore, it is worth verifying that Avinash's solution works on large data (300 M).